# Average Time for Month formula not working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_UqzjZ2V8rso4CvtEevSq8uDe5H_qt4-rgY0x-RWE7s/edit?usp=sharing

Hello, I'm trying to calculate the average time for the current month but I keep getting error messages. I've searched around and found similar issues but their solutions didn't work for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have pasted the link above to the google sheet and removed restrictions so it should be editable for anyone with the link.

The formula I used was =AVERAGEIF(B2:B9,D11,E2:E9)

Comment: Your formula makes little sense.  You are trying to compare a Date in the **Date** column with a string in `D11`.  They will never be the same so you have a `div/0` error. But in addition, you are trying to average a column of text entries -- your Total Time column is text since your formula for the Total Time function is using the Text function to show the results. Although Excel will sometimes try to convert Text to numbers, `AVERAGE` functions purposely ignore Text.  Think about data types, and be sure to use the appropriate data types for the operation you are trying to perform.

Comment: Yeah that was just the last way I tired getting it to work based off of some other stuff I found. Got it going now though. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to edit the google sheet, but here is how it could be done:

Firstly, let's change the 'Total time' column to the following: `=24*(D2-C2)` - this is a number rather than text.

Secondly, let's create a 'MONTH_CODE' column, say in column 'F', where `=MONTH(B2)` (getting the numerical month of a given date.

Finally, in 'D12', `=AVERAGEIF(F2:F9, MONTH(DATEVALUE(D11&"1")), E2:E9)`

Comment: Sorry, it's on editor now. Had it on viewer

Comment: When I type in =Month(B2) it returns January

Comment: NVM. That was only in column A for some reason